# Second Paint Slot Not Showing Details in Texture Mode

Tags: texture-painting

Hoping someone can help!

I'm quite new to blender, so I apologize if my terminology isn't quite accurate.

I'm working on a character model.
I'm using blender render.
I've just finished unwrapping everything, and have laid down a base color layer in my paint slots. This all worked fine.

I've added a second Paint slot and turned the alpha down to zero, essentially using this one as the "detail" painting. But nothing I do on this second layer can be seen in my viewport.

I'm in texture mode. I have a Hemi light in my scene. I'm following Darrin Lile's tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHTakjMTVWQ

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

See Screenshot below

[image: Blender Screenshot]

Comment: Is your 0 alpha image set as the active slot in the Slots tab?What is the mix mode of that texture slot/image texture?

Comment: It was active so that wasn't the problem, but your question made me find the solution! Apparently the order of the paint slots in the texture tab matters, I didn't realize I'd done it backwards. Switched them around and all works good now

Answer (score 1):

Changing around the order of the paint slots in the texture tab is what solved my problem. I had them backwards. I put my base layer at the top, and my detail layer 2nd and it's working fine now!

[image: solved]