# Painting on the second texture slot applying to incorrect UV image

Tags: uv, texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

I put some base colors on my mesh using the first texture slot created automatically. Now I need to add some color details. I added new texture slot for it, connected it to a new UV image. Active slot is slot 2 (the one for color details).

The problem is that when I paint on the mesh having active slot 2 everything is painted on the image connected to slot 1 (with base color) and I expect seeing painting results on color details image.

Changing the order of slots as described in similar question doesn't help ([Second Paint Slot Not Showing Details in Texture Mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108205/second-paint-slot-not-showing-details-in-texture-mode))
Unfortunately, I cannot attach my .blend file via https://pasteall.org/blend/ because it exceeds maximum size(24Mb).
Here's the link for the tutorial I follow and below my screenshot attached. Thank you in advance for your help!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHTakjMTVWQ&list=PLyelx0TsmSpeQE2LpgM8Qwnco-9mrNG0O&index=3&t=1s

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(The video linked in the question is about Blender 2.7. I didn't know that Blender can mix color layers automatically. But it doesn't work for me in Blender 2.8+).

In Blender 2.8 (or higher) you can see the texture of the slot that you have selected in *Solid* shading mode (<kbd>Z</kbd>). But it does not mix the slots with the alpha value. When the texture slot has an Alpha channel it displays the model transparent where the alpha value is 0. At these spots the model is invisible.

To get the layered effect as shown in the video you need to mix the images in the shader editor. The base color is black, in the example. And red & green are the details. The alpha value of this image determines what color is shown.

[image: shader editor]

To see the material you need to switch the shading mode (<kbd>Z</kbd>) to *Material Preview* or *Rendered*. Then you can see both texture slots mixed together. In the *Texture Paint* workspace now you can select a *Texture Slot* in the *Tool Settings* and paint on that image that is connected to the slot via *Image Texture* node.

[image: texture painting]
Use *Alpha Erase* brush mode to remove the details and reveal the base color.

Comment: Wow, mix node does its work and I can see the results as expected, thank you! There're 2 things that are not so good in this case.
1. Material preview gives me sort of flat or overlightened image in 3d view (attached Image2 to the question), is that ok?
2. In other workspaces like modelling geometry and base color texture are not visible and only details are shown. Do you know how to fix that? (Image3 attached to the question)

Comment: And what is more, the author of the tutorial creates some more texture slots in the next videos adding bump information in normal material. How can I use some more images if mix node has only 2 colors?

Comment: 1. Yes, that's ok. You're in *Material Preview* shading mode and you have unchecked *Scene Lights* and *Scene World* so Blender uses the build-in HDRI. That's the sphere in the options. You can click it and choose another lighting setup. Or check the 2 checkboxes & you will have the same lighting as in your render. 2. Yes, this is what I meant. You are in *Solid* shading mode, and Blender makes the model partly invisible. But the *Solid* mode has also options. Try *Color > Random* or *Color > Object* to see the model in solid colors. Or switch the shading mode to *Material Preview* (Z key, 2)

Comment: You can add a 3rd layer with another *Image Texture* and *MixRGB* node: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wglwa.jpg (This example uses 4 colors and 3 masks. In your case the masks are the *Alpha* channels and the colors are the *Color* channel of the *Image Texture* node). Maybe have a look here: https://youtu.be/Cai6z45_UXM. --  A *Bump* map can be added the same way: Add an *Image Texture* node, set Color Space to *Non-Color* in this node, and connect it to a *Bump* node => https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/135472/107598

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and detailed explanation!